# getArguments() always returning null in my second fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, parameter-passing, mobile-application

I know the question has been asked too many times but none proves to be working for me.
I'm trying to pass the input in an EditText of Fragment1 to a TextView in Fragment2 using an interface and both sharing one Activity, but I've been stucked at it for more than a day now. The problem is that the argument I'm sending from the MainActivity is always null.

This is my Interface:

```
interface SendData {
    fun sendData(name: String)
}
```

And the Fragment1.kt:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var communicator: SendData

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false)
        communicator = activity as SendData

        rootView.btn_send.setOnClickListener {
            communicator.sendData(rootView.name_ET.text.toString())
        }
        return rootView
    }
}
```

Fragment2.kt

```
class Fragment2 : Fragment() {

    var receivedName: String? = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        receivedName = arguments?.getString("NAME")
        Log.d("Fragment2", "Receiving: ${arguments.toString()}")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, false)

        rootView.receivedName_TV.text = receivedName

        return rootView
    }
}
```

And the MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SendData {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment1())
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit()
    }

    override fun sendData(name: String) {
        Fragment2().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString("NAME", name)
            }
            Log.d("Fragment1", "Sending: ${arguments.toString()}")
        }
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2())
            .addToBackStack("Fragment2").setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit()
    }
}
```

I'm using a [resource](https://github.com/johncodeos-blog/PassDataFragmentsExample) and I even compared my code with theirs line by line and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2())
```

on new fragment not the one you used apply
try

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString("NAME", name)
        })
```

and deleting this part above

```
Fragment2().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString("NAME", name)
        }
```

basically what I am trying to say is your function should look like this

```
override fun sendData(name: String) {

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString("NAME", name)
        }
    })
        .addToBackStack("Fragment2").setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit()
}
```

or

```
override fun sendData(name: String) {
    val f =Fragment2().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString("NAME", name)
        }
        Log.d("Fragment1", "Sending: ${arguments.toString()}")
    }
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f)
        .addToBackStack("Fragment2").setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit()
}
```

Comment: Wao. I'm really grateful for this. It's fine now. It didn't occur to me that was the problem at all. :)